# Multiple parents and multiple children in product categories

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am making a ecommerce site. In this site I want to categorise the items into three different layers

```
primary category             sub category           sub category

>>electronic             >>smart phone          samsung
  cameras                       tablets              nokia  
                                laptop               apple
                                headphone
```

In the above table, I want to display the **sub category** after the customer selects the **primary** one. At the same time the 'samsung' also comes under 'camera'. Like this a parent can have any number of children and one child can have many parents. In the future we may change the **primary** and **secondary**.

What is the best solution for this?
Which model will adopt our category: tree or nested?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Can an item belong to 2 sub-sub-categories, like both "nokia" and "apple"? Can an item belong to 2 (different level) categories, like "laptop" and "nokia"? Or is any item related (belongs to) one and only one category or sub-category?

Comment: For the categories, are there exactly 3 levels as you show and no more? And can a category belong to different level (as in your example, "samsung" is in level-3 under "smart phone", and in level-2 under "camera")?.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider Postgres, as it does hierarchical querying better than Mysql. If using Mysql, consider using a closure table to aid querying.

I think you are actually confusing Brand and sub-sub-category. You should have a brand table too.

```
create table category (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null,
  parent_id int null references category(id)
);


create table brand (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null unique
);


create table brand_category (
  brand_id int not null references brand(id),
  category_id int not null references category(id),
  primary key (brand_id, category_id)
);


/* the product specification, not the actual product asset instance: */
create table product (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null,
  brand_id int not null references brand(id)
);


create table product_category (
  product_id int not null references product(id),
  category_id int not null references category(id),
  primary key (product_id, category_id)
);
```

example:

```
/* null parent_id means top-level category */
insert into category values

(1, 'Electronics', null),
(2, 'Cameras', null),

(3, 'Smart Phones', 1),
(4, 'Tablets', 1),
(5, 'Laptops', 1),
(6, 'Headphones', 1);


insert into brand values 
(1, 'Samsung'),
(2, 'Nokia'),
(3, 'Apple');


/* samsung brand in both smartphones and cameras: */
insert into brand_category values
(1, 3),
(1, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 3);


insert into product values 
(1, 'Samsung Model X', 1);


/* add samsung model x as a smart phone: */
insert into product_category values
(1, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to expand Neil's point above by showing what a hierarchical query would look like in PostgreSQL.  I will also concur that this is a significant weak point in MySQL because recursive queries are not supported.

Suppose we want to traverse upwards from product to see the full classification.  The query would look like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE product_chain (id, path, parent_id, category_name) AS (
   SELECT c.id, c.name, parent_id, c.name
     FROM category 
    WHERE id in (SELECT category_id FROM product_category 
                  WHERE product_id = 1)
UNION ALL
   SELECT c.id, c.name || '/' || pc.path, c.parent_id, c.name
     FROM category 
     JOIN product_chain pc ON pc.parent_id = c.id
 )
 SELECT p.*, pc.path
   FROM product p
   JOIN product_chain pc ON pc.parent_id IS NULL
  WHERE p.id = 1;
```

Similarly we can generate the entire category tree with something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cat_tree (id, level, path) AS (
   SELECT c.id, 1, c.name
     FROM category c WHERE parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
   SELECT c.id, ct.level + 1, ct.path || '/' || c.name
     FROM category c
     JOIN cat_tree ct ON c.parent_id = ct.id
 )
 select c.name, ct.path, ct.level
   FROM category c
   JOIN cat_tree ct ON c.id = ct.id;
```

Both of these perform remarkably well on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Recursive SQL using a Common Table Expression (CTE) was introduced in MySQL version 8.0 and MariaDB version 10.2.2.